# Django refuse to connect HTML that without have HTTP protocol

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, iframe

Hi I wish to IFRAME HTML code in my django, but unfortunately it fail to show out contain.

**template.html**

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
title="Inline Frame Example"
width="300"
height="200"
src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik">
</iframe> 
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
title="Inline Frame Example"
width="300"
height="200"
src="C:/Graph/GraphCombine/templates/T.html">
</iframe>
```

For the first IFRAME it work, but for the second iframe, the content are not showing up,anyone can share me ideas?

**EDIT**

I have solve the above problem by the following code

```
src="{% static 'A.html' %}"
```

But I face another problem that is the html file is unknown in future so i loop the html file in array and pass to html by following code:

```
graph=['A.html']
{% for i in graph %}
src="{% static '{{i|safe}}' %}" 
{% endfor %}
```

But I get **Error**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: What's the error message you get in the browser's console?

Comment: I get this error A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

Comment: Please check for browser side error messages. *Right Click > Inspect*, then choose the *Console* tab. Is there any error message? And to see the django side errors, please check your django logs on the server.

Comment: @xyres I saw this :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: But now I face new problem again, the html file is unknown in future, so i will used python array to loop it out: src="{% static '{i|safe}' %}"  but I get back same error  :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: You can't use this - `{ }` inside this - `{% %}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190660/discussion-between-shi-jie-tio-and-xyres).